# EntityFieldQuery causing column not found PDO exception

Tags: nodes, database, entities

I have a very simple node type set up in drupal, see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we4JU.jpg)

And I'm trying to get the node id based on the email field (the email is unique to each node, just like the nid). My query looks like this:

```
$query  -> entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
-> entityCondition('bundle', 'mail_entry')
-> fieldCondition('field_email', 'value', $email);
```

But drupal is complaining with:

> "PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'field_data_field_email0.field_email_value'"

I don't really understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess you're using the [Email Field](http://drupal.org/project/email/) module to provide that particular field?

If so, the column name is `email`, not `value`, so your code should be:

```
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'mail_entry')
  ->fieldCondition('field_email', 'email', $email);
```

Comment: Thanks, I worked this out not too long ago. This works perfectly.

Comment: It seems this Exeption is generally thrown if the column parameter of the fieldCondition() method is wrong.